# A moderator understood and answered my question but put it was put on hold as unclear?

Tags: discussion, bug, questions, closed-questions

I asked this question  [Zero Radiation Nuclear Bomb Possible?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/369414/zero-radiation-nuclear-bomb-possible)  and a moderator completely understood my question, provided an answer and mention he would like to see other answers, but it still got put on hold for being unclear after he posted. How is this? I believe that it was too quickly dismissed without thoroughly reading it by each persons who closed it.

Comment: Several points (A) That question was submitted for review when you edited it after it was closed and that review is still on-going. (B) Though it may or may not be so in this case, someone can guess the intended meaning in a unclear muddle, so a answer the asker likes does not demonstrate clarity. (C) You've made four @-tagged comments, a moderator flag and a meta-post in the hour since you edited the question, but this is not Stack Oveflow and we don't have millions of users standing by at every moment; these things take time.

Comment: To follow up on @dmckee's comments, the [review](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/196589) is now completed and there will be no further system action on your thread unless you initiate it (or somebody independently votes to reopen, which I would class as highly unlikely). As it stands, without substantial clarifying of what it's asking on your part, I don't think it's suitable for reopening and I don't think you'll find enough people who think it is to reopen it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [...] How is this?

I'm guessing that you're asking how it's possible that a moderator answered your question and then it got put on hold. Simply, there's nothing that makes it impossible. There's no rule or anything like that which keeps questions from being put on hold after they have answers. (Regardless of who posts the answer.)

> I believe that it was too quickly dismissed without thoroughly reading it by each persons who closed it.

Well then, you basically have two options:

- You can just edit your question to clarify it anyway. That is, make it so that even someone who *doesn't* spend enough time reading the question will get an unambiguous sense of what it's asking. After the edit, the question will automatically be placed in a queue to be reviewed, and if enough people agree that the edit fixes the issue that caused it to be closed, the hold gets removed (i.e. the question gets reopened).
- You can try to convince five site members with reopen vote privileges, or one moderator, that the question is fine as is - that is, that all five people who voted to put your question on hold made an outright wrong decision. Honestly, this does not usually work. The bar for convincing people that five close voters all made an error is *very* high. That being said, if you want to do this, the best way is by making a meta post clearly laying out an argument for why you think the original decision to put the question on hold was wrong.

Comment: I have done both as you said.